# git/svn Hooks for PHP/Zend Projects

Tags: php, git, svn, zend-framework

just because i think we are not using the full potential of all possibilites here yet:
What Pre/Post Commit Hooks (i.e. PHPUnit, PHPDoc) do you people use on your Team Git/SVN Servers?
By now we do use a minification script (sadly only removes unneccessary space and comments and merges files), PHPDoc, PHPUnit and that's it already.

Any good ideas that might be usefull as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a Jenkins setup that runs Sebastiann Bergman's default template, including pdepend, phploc, phpmd, to analyse style quality, architecture quality and the likes.

http://jenkins-php.org/

We've already greatly improved the quality of our codebase since we started using it a few weeks ago :)

Comment: Actually someone over here already started working with Jenkins a day before i posted this question. I too find it very usefull so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use a pre-commit hook that checks for proper indentation and styling.

Comment: Well this really can't have only one valid answer i guess and i aparently don't have enough reputation for upvoting yet but i'd like to point out that i do thank you for your answer.